# Acceder a fichero SQL desde Java y DriverManager

Tags: java, sql

Tengo un fichero de base de datos `SQL` al cual quiero acceder desde una clase Java que hace la conexión a `DriverManager` y `JDBC`, pero estoy un poco perdido.

el fichero se llama items.sql

DBItem.java

```
package beans;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author elcer
 */
public class DBItem {
    private String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/items";

    private Connection conn = null;

    public DBItem() { //el constructor crea y abre la conexion
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "usuario", "password");
            if (conn != null) 
                System.out.println("Conexion efectuada con exito");                    
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger
                (DBItem.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public LinkedList<Item> getItems(String tipo) {
        LinkedList<Item> itemsTipo = new LinkedList<>();
        if (conn != null) {
            try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
                String sqls = "SELECT * from items WHERE tipo='" + tipo + "'"; 
                try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqls)) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        String nombre = rs.getString("nombre");
                        Item item = new Item(nombre, tipo);
                        itemTipo.add(item);
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DBItem.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return itemsTipo;
    }

    public void closeDB() {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBItem.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

intento acceder a la base de datos, pero no me la reconoce, me dice que no se puede inicializar y tal...
¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Hola Álvaro. Échale un vistazo a las secciones [ask] y [mcve]. Aportando el código problemático facilitas que la gente pueda ayudarte. Bienvenido a SOes.

Comment: intento acceder a la base de datos, pero no me la reconoce, me dice que no se puede inicializar y tal...

Answer (score 0):

**DriverManager** permite conectar con una Base de Datos. Si lo que tienes es un fichero con código SQL (entiendo que sería un fichero de texto plano, con las queries para crear tablas, inserts, etc., que puedes abrir y leer, sin usar Java) para acceder a los mismos desde Java como quieres hacer primero tienen que estar en la Base de Datos. Si no están puedes usar **DriverManager** y **JDBC** para introducirlos, después de **leer el contenido del fichero** y preparar los datos de la forma que convenga.

Saludos.

Comment: Orici, el autor ha modificado su pregunta (bueno, está en ello hehe ) mira a ver si tu respuesta puede ser mejorada

Comment: y lo último, exactamente como se hace? porque eso nunca lo he hecho. tengo que crearme una clase aparte para leer el fichero SQL?

Answer (score 0):

La clase que has puesto lo que hace es abrir una conexión (en el constructor) y proveer un método para recuperar un listado de items, de un determinado tipo como LinkedList.

Ahora, supongamos que ya tienes la BD creada, donde existe la tabla **items**, donde ya tienes registros. Con esta clase podrás recuperar parte de esos registros.

Si tu fichero SQL tiene solo queries de inserción de registros válidas, puedes leerlo (Si deberías crearte una clase para esto, usando File, FileInputStream, etc), volcar el contenido leido en un string, y luego, supongiendo que lo que tengas sea una querie de inserción, abrir la conexión con la BD, crear un **Statement** y usar **executeUpdate()** sobre éste para almacenar los datos.
Un método para insertar un registro para la clase que ya tienes podría ser éste:

```
public void insert( String sql_insert ) {
            System.out.println( "Ejecutando sentencia SQL..." );

            try ( Statement st = this.conn.createStatement( )) {
                System.out.println( "Statement creado !" );

                st.executeUpdate( arr_sql[ i ] );


                System.out.println( "Cerrando conexión..." );
                st.close();

            } catch( SQLException e ) {

                System.out.println( "Error realizando insert." );
                System.out.println( "---> " + e.toString( ));
            }
        }
```

Si no entiendes nada de lo que te he dicho, te queda mucho que estudiar, mirate algun tutorial sencillo, por ejemplo, este: http://picarcodigo.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/jdbc-conexion-bases-de-datos-mysql.html